# How does I aware from this type of errors in python

Tags: python

I written a code having an function 
Def product(a,b,c)
And declared those values at the end 
But when I'm using these variables in program or if and else statements 
It is  showing an undefined 'a' name error 
Please help me it always showing this error how to rectify it.

Comment: Please show your code and the full error

Comment: please provide some code of your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Error**'s on your code were due to:

1. incorrect indentation
2. wrong declaration of variable `rupees_to_make`.

The **Logical** **Errors** in your code were:-

1. Variable `five_needed` expects a integer as an input, but gets
   float on your code because `five_needed = rupees_to_make/5` (on
   python 3.x) resolves to a floating point number.
2. The Logical error of the previous line, eventually causes variable `one_needed` to store a floating value too.

**Rectified Code:-**

```
def make_amount(rupees_to_make, no_of_five, no_of_one):

    five_needed = rupees_to_make//5
    one_needed = rupees_to_make - (5*five_needed)

    if rupees_to_make > (5*no_of_five+no_of_one):
        print(-1)

    elif five_needed < no_of_five and one_needed < no_of_one:
        print("No. of Five needed :", five_needed)
        print("No. of One needed :", one_needed)

    else:
        print(-1)


make_amount(28, 8, 5)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
No. of Five needed : 5
No. of One needed : 3
```

From Your style of code, I believe that you are new to Python language, and came from a non-weakly typed language background (C, C++, Java etc).(Cause you were using redundant parenthesis after each expression, and initializing a variable with a value before using it which is, uncommon/wasteful in Python as variables are weakly typed in Python). Try avoiding their use, unless necessary from later on.

Comment: Thanks sir it is worked

Comment: But sir when I written like this but I didn't place // this to obtain integer value when division performed ,why it shows undefined name and please give me some tips to write more python programs as I am preparing for tcs and infosys exams as I'm approaching to final year and help me to grow in logic building please sir

Comment: I have edited your question to be a lot straightforward, so accept that edit, If this answer solved your problem then mark it as correct so, in the future if others had the same problem they can solve it easily via the answer. If you want to practice python program's [This will help](https://www.practicepython.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you declared those values at the end of your function it's normal that it do not work, you need to declare them at the begining of your function before to use them.

Comment: yes, sorry I just realised that I am not really clear. But if he had to declare them at the end of his code, maeby it is better to declare them at the begenning

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is the fact that variables in a function are not global (able to be used out of the function) by default.

So if you have something like this:

```
def product (a,b,c):
    #do something
    a = "something"
    b = "something"
    c = "something"


print(a)
```

You will get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` error, since `a` can't be used out of the function

To get around this, return the values from your function and then print them.

You can't return multiple values individually, but you can add them to a list and then return it.

Eg.

```
def product (a,b,c):
    #do something
    a = "something"
    b = "something"
    c = "something"
    return [a,b,c]

p = product (1,2,3)

print(p[0]) #prints a, which is 'something'
print(p[1]) #prints b, which is 'something'
print(p[2]) #prints c, which is 'something'
```

OR ...

Use the global keyword.

```
def product (a,b,c):
    #do something
    global a = "something"
    global b = "something"
    global c = "something"


print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

>>> something
>>> something
>>> something
```

Note that this method is dangerous if you have, for instance, a var `a` defined before the function, since it will be overridden if you define `global a` in your function.

---